# How to scale MNIST from 28*28 to 29*29 in Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I was trying to apply deformation to MNIST dataset. The very first step of doing elastic distortion is to scale each image from 28*28 to 29*29 in order to simplify Gaussian convolution.

But almost every publications mentioned this procedure ended up with saying "scale it from 28*28 to 29*29". And nothing more...

So my question is, is there any specific implementation to do this with python, particularly with each image arranged as a 2-D numpy array.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple choices for image resizing.

```
import numpy as np
img28 = np.eye(28)
from skimage.transform import resize
img29r = resize(img, (29, 29))
from scipy.misc import imresize
img29i = imresize(img, (29, 29))
```

It's a matter of taste and specifics of your application which you want to use.